# I have made a Windows bat script for archiving old files from a list. Any suggestions for the syntax on the code?

Tags: windows, syntax, batch-file, archive

Not sure what the setlocal is for, but I found it in a script example for something else that required multiple commands in a for loop.

Filelist.txt holds a list of files with the full file path to a share.

For example: \\FileShare\Division\Project\file.txt

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filelist.txt) do (
mkdir "D:\Archive\%%~dpi"
move "%%i" "D:\Archive\%%i")
endlocal
```

The script takes the files in filelist.txt (line by line) and copies the directory structure of the path then moves the file over. Using my example above it creates the directory D:\Archive\FileShare\Division\Project\ and then moves the file **file.txt** to that directory.

I sort of pieced this together from existing examples of different tasks that I found on here. Any tips on cleaning it up?

Edit: To address a comment from will below. The script was created to work off a report generated of files that had not been accessed in over a year. This is why it needed to work off a list of files because I wanted to keep the folder structure and all the other files intact. If there was some way to integrate this into the script that would be awesome!

Comment: For your application would it make more sense for you to copy all of the files/folder taken from a list of directories, instead of having to list every file that you want archived?

Comment: @will This script worked off of a list generated by a report. The report was for all files not accessed in the last year or more. Would there be a way to just integrate that into the script?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `delayed expansion` or the `setlocal`.  `setlocal` will isolate the scope of the section so that any changes made to variables are kept isolated to that scope.  Delayed expansion is only needed if you are expanding variables within loops or if statements.  There is not much to really cleanup with your script.  If it accomplishes your tasks without issue and does so efficiently, then there is no need for change.

Changes and Why

1. `setlocal EnableExtensions`  The scope isolation is not needed but Extensions must be enabled to use the `for /f` option.
2. `%%F` instead of `%%i` because capital letters are more easily differentiated from the modifiers. (Readability)
3. `if exist "%%~fA"` to verify that the file in the list still exists when the script is run.
4. `for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%D in ("%%~dF") do` because folder names cannot contain colons.  This will remove the colon character from the file path for the drive.
5. `&&` Only try moving the file if the destination was crated successfully.

Code:

```
rem Hide the Command Output.
@echo off
rem Isolate Variable Scope and Enable Extensions.
setlocal EnableExtensions
rem Loop through the file list and verify file existence.
for /f "delims=" %%F in (filelist.txt) do if exist "%%~fF" (
    rem Parse the drive letter since colon : is not a valid folder character.
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%D in ("%%~dF") do (
        rem Create the folder hierarchy
        mkdir "D:\Archive\%%~D\%%~pF" && move "%%~fF" "D:\Archive\%%~D\%%~pF"
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you David! I was wondering how to get that : removed. Sounds like a good list, I'll try em out and adjust according.